# sql put " inside "" when doing a bulk insert stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

My procedure for bulk insert is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_impt]
AS 
BEGIN
   Declare @SQL1 varchar(150), @path varchar(100), 
           @pathtable varchar(100), @date datetime

   set @date = getdate()

   -- set path for files
   set @path= '\\ff\avc\ce\ed_imp\'
   set @pathtable = @path + 'ABC20140723.csv'

   -- Delete data from tables
   delete from table1

   --  set sql
   set @SQL1 = "BULK INSERT dbo.table1 FROM '" + @pathtable 
               + "' WITH (FIRSTROW = 3,MAXERRORS = 0,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')"

   -- Bulk insert
   exec(@sql1)
end
```

It works fine except when my data has "Google,Inc", it is converted to "Google" "Inc".
I want to write FIELDTERMINATOR = '","' instead of ',', however, I don't know how to put it into my `@sql1` string?

Also, is it recommended I write a format file? My csv file has 200 columns and rows. Do I need to write each row? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't do this with BULK INSERT as is.  BULK INSERT can't tell what comma is a delimiter and what comma is part of the data.  Your source data apparently doesn't have the string field values quoted (i.e. surrounded by quotes).  For comma separated fields, if ANY of the data contains a comma, it must be surrounded by quotation marks or BULK INSERT will view it as a field terminator.  You will have to update your source data to surround strings with quotation marks before inserting.

I ran into this frequently while running data loads from text files and csv files.  The only solution was to get the source of the data to add quotes or to use a different delimiter, such as a pipe ( | ) or to switch to fixed width fields.   In either case, the source data has to be fixed.